# Axios response not running in react component

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have this code to fetch data from a MongoDB db, I'm using the DataAPI. Now, it works perfectly when I run it in a separate .js file and run it using node .js. But when I run it as part of a react component outside the return function, nothing happens. Here is the code for reference:

```
//THIS CODE LOGS THE EXPECTED RESPONSE FROM MONGO TO THE CONSOLE
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';


//const [Story, setStory] = useState([]);
console.log("???? start");
var data = JSON.stringify({
    "collection": "shortstories",
    "database": "Documents",
    "dataSource": "writingcluster",
    
});

var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://ap-south-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-rvxaz/endpoint/data/v1/action/findOne',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Request-Headers': '*',
        'api-key': 'API KEY HERE',
    },
    data: data
};

axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

but, when I use it like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";



const Mainpage = () => {

    const [Story, setStory] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                console.log("???? start");
                var data = JSON.stringify({
                    "collection": "shortstories",
                    "database": "Documents",
                    "dataSource": "writingcluster",
                });

                var config = {
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'https://ap-south-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-rvxaz/endpoint/data/v1/action/findOne',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Access-Control-Request-Headers': '*',
                        'api-key': 'SAME API KEY',
                    },
                    data: data
                };

                axios(config)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        setStory(response.data);
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));

                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div class="main">
            <div class="line" style={{
                width: "1.5px", height: "100%", backgroundColor: "#ffffff", marginLeft: "75%", position:
                    "absolute"
            }}>

            </div>
```

nothing happens. What's the issue here? Maybe the code is not being run, and only pushed to the DOM?

I've tried restructuring the code in the component in many ways, using a hook, using different types of axios calls etc. I'm at the end of my wits. Help me!